# Migrar bases de datos de un servidor mysql a otro

Tags: mysql

Tengo en un equipo1 corriendo un servidor mysql con 2 bases de datos (bd1 y bd2).

Estas bases de datos se encuentran dentro de la carpeta data:
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data

Por otra parte, en otro equipo2, tengo otro servidor mysql (misma version mysql), con 2 bases de datos corriendo (bd3 y bd4).

Mi pregunta es: ¿Es posible "sacar" las bd3 y bd4 y montarlas en la carpeta data del equipo1?

La finalidad es tener un solo equipo con las 4 bases de datos.

Lo que hice fue:

1. Detener el servicio mysql del equipo1.
2. Copiar las carpetas bd3 y bd4 del equipo2 y pegarlas en la carpeta data del equipo1.
3. Iniciar el servicio mysql en el equipo1.

El servicio levanta y puedo ver las 4 bases de datos, pero por desgracia las bd3 y bd4 no se pueden abrir.

¿Que me falta por hacer?

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

PD. Hablo de mysql para windows.

Comment: Sin ser un dbadmin de mysql, creo que la que quieres hacer no se hace de esa forma. Debes crear `dumps` de las DBs y luego montas los dumps en el otro servidor. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html

Comment: Hola @eftshift0, si se puede, hace algunos años lo hice con un tutorial que vi en una pagina, pero ya no encuentro esa pagina.

Comment: Efectivamente, lo de copiar las carpetas hace ya varias versiones de MySQL que no funciona... Si quieres hacerlo aún más fácil utiliza, desde phpMyAdmin, Exportar e Importar

Answer (score 0):

Cuando la Base de Datos fue creada como InnoDB no funcionan al usar copiar pegar.

Te sugiero uses el phpMyAdmin para [crear y restaurar respaldo](https://support.managed.com/kb/a2034/how-to-backup-and-or-restore-your-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin.aspx).

Si por alguna razón no puedes o te marca errores el antes mencionado te sugiero descargues un software que soporte o sea para MySQL y desde luego lo instales en la BD origen y a donde la moveras para que realices respaldo en una y luego en otra restaures.
Desde luego lo anterior si puedes conectarte a ambas BBDD instalando en un solo equipo es lo idóneo.

Yo te sugiero por ejemplo el Navicat para MySQL pero ahí el que te sea más intuitivo.

Answer (score 0):

Las carpetas que copiaste y pusiste en el nuevo servidor no son validas como respaldo y deberias borrarlas de la carpeta de datos de mysql de destino, y reiniciar el servidor de destino antes de realizar el import.

Esto es debido a que es probable que sean bases de datos dinamicas INNODB o semejante, las cuales guardan parte de sus transaciones en archivos intermedios como el InnoDb log (ver https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-backup.html). Solo las bases de datos de tipo MyISAM se podrian copiar de esta manera ya que cada transaccion pasa al archivo de datos inmediatamente.

En el servidor de bd3 y bd4 debes crear un dump de las bases de datos usando `mysqldump` (esta en la carpeta bin de la instalacion de MySQL):

```
mysqldump.exe -u root -p --opt bd3 > bd3.sql
mysqldump.exe -u root -p --opt bd4 > bd4.sql
```

Luego estos archivos los copias al servidor de destino y ejecutas un import. REcuerda que las BD copiadas a mano deben borrarse y reiniciar el servidor mysql.

Para importar los dumps en el destino, usando el cliente `mysql`

```
mysql.exe -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE bd3"
mysql.exe -u root -p bd3 < file.sql

mysql.exe -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE bd4"
mysql.exe -u root -p bd4 < file.sql
```

Otra manera menos engorrosa es exportar los datos usando PHPMyAdmin, en la opcion **Export**, exportando la base de datos entera. Luego ese mismo respaldo lo cargas usando **Import** en el servidor destino. Pero de la misma manera, se debe al menos crear la base de datos en blanco antes de importar.

Hay muchos otros metodos para diferentes casos. Puedes consultar la documentacion en https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html